# Optimising a database with two separate category tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a database for a website that provides all the data storage capabilities of the website. It stores articles in a knowlegebase, and services for internal and end-user access.

Both articles and services are stored in categories which can have an indefinite amount of parent categories by self-referencing. It is possible to add multiple categories to either via the connecting table.

[image: The Schema]

It needs to be possible to find the categories of a service or an article, including all the way up the category-parent tree. It also needs to be possible to find the services or articles of a category. Of course, a category can't have both.

Is this an optimal way of doing this? It doesn't feel right, and I'd welcome alternate ideas.

EDIT: Does this way usually work? The categories all have roughly the same content, just a name and description and perhaps an image.

[image: Alternative]

Comment: You could maybe use STI in this case!

Comment: @mahatmanich How does that work, in this case? I'd also thought about using a single category table and a 'type' field, since then I could cover multiple sections of the database that requires categories. Categories are all just name, description, and url slug, basically, although I might add images in the future.

Comment: Is the many-to-many relation between categories and services/articles for recording the path up the category tree for each service/article, or can services/articles really belong to different leaf node categories?

Comment: @reaanb I'm not 100% sure what that means, embarassingly, but I do want to be able to trace the path upwards. The services/articles can belong to different categories.

Answer (score 0):

The primary keys of `category_service` and `category_article` should include both fields in the respective tables (if a category can have more than one service or article).  Also, do you really need a VARCHAR(45) type indicator?  I recommend a short ENUM instead.

Otherwise, the basic design in the second diagram looks good.  I suggest you add a [closure table](http://technobytz.com/closure_table_store_hierarchical_data.html) for efficiently querying recursive hierarchies.

If you want to enforce consistency between the category type and records in `category_article`/`category_service`, you can duplicate the type indicator in those tables and include it in the foreign key constraint.  Yes, doing so feels redundant, but it's effective.  Resist the temptation to combine these two tables, mixing values from different domains in a single column usually leads to more difficulties.

Comment: The categories probably would work interchangably, but they both need to be referenced differently. For example, the article category listing cannot show service categories, and vice versa.